# Docker build slow on EC2 (Amazon Linux)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I provisioned an instance from Amazon Machine Image based on Amazon Linux (amzn-ami-2016.03.c-amazon-ecs-optimized). While attempting to do a `docker build` for my project, I find the process extremely slow, even for simple tasks like setting environment variables `ENV TEST_PORT=3000` etc. A build that takes less than 5 minutes on my local machine has been running for at least an hour.

Running `docker info` returns Storage as `devicemapper` and this [article](http://www.danstutzman.com/2014/07/speed-up-docker-on-ec2) suggests switching to `aufs` but it is for Ubuntu. I also have an EBS volume attached to my instance, how do I switch docker to use that instead? Will that fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem : each simple step of the Dockerfile (like ENV or ARG) is taking one or twe seconds on my Amazon Linux EC2 box.
To solve this, I have to :

- upgrade Docker to version 17.03.2-ce
- switch the overlay driver of docker, as suggested by https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/ . There is a dedicated section for CentOS.
- I created /etc/docker/daemon.json with the following content :

  {
   "storage-driver": "overlay2",
   "storage-opts": [
    "overlay2.override_kernel_check=true"
   ]
  }
- stop and start the docker daemon.

Now each simple step are very fast.